# Slide finger to tap another imagebutton

Tags: android

I have 4x4 imagebuttons in my app. their function is, whenever they are tapped/clicked, they will display a a text on a textview based on what image assigned to them. Now, i want to form a word using this imagebuttons. How can i connect the imagebuttons by just sliding my finger from one imagebutton to another?

I saw this question ([Sliding finger across multiple image views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535500/sliding-finger-across-multiple-image-views)) and I think we have the same question. But I didnt get what the answers mean ESPECIALLY on how to do it. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

This is the code i am currently using. This is for single tap of only.

```
image1.setOnClickListener(myCommoClickListener)
//same as the rest

OnClickListener myCommoClickListner = new OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
Log.i(TAG,"arg0.getId() = " + arg0.getId());

if(arg0.getId()==R.drawable.lettera){
Log.i(TAG,"arg0.getId()="+arg0.getId());
generatedString=generatedString+"a";
text.setText(generatedString);

//start countdowntimer
```

Note: I am a newbie in android programming. I would be very thankful if you'll also help me with the codes.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? The "duplicate" question's responses tell to manage TouchEvent on the containing view instead of the buttons themselves.

Comment: No, becuase i dont know how to do it. All i have is the onclicklistener of all those 16 imagebuttons. can you help me with this? I really dont know how to make it that way